# How to insert 100k entries into 3 tables with foreign key Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have an array where each element contains array

```
        $arryItem = [
            'surname' => 'user_surname',
            'name' => 'user_name',
            'sex' => 'user_sex',
            'ratio' => 'player_ratio'
        ];
```

Also I have 3 tables. Users, Players and users_roles

```
users
id | name | surname | sex

players
id | user_id | ratio

users_roles
user_id | role_id
```

On each iteration I have to

1. Create user and get inserted ID
2. Create player and insert user_id as inserted user ID
3. Create new entry into users_roles, where user_id will inserted user ID

The problem is that there will 100k+ iterations with 3 inserts and other logic such as srtolower, generate random email and password. I think that my script will fail with timeout or memory limit.

Are there ways to do this fast? DB - PostgreSQL

Comment: "You think", did you try?

Comment: No, but i started the script 20 minutes ago

Comment: 100k isn't that much. What do you expect from us really?

Comment: Yep. thanks for help